# Update unicodepwd in ActiveDirectory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to update the unicodePwd attribute in WindowsAD. I am using ldaps://server:636 to get the InitialContext created. The connection is just fine and I am able to search for a record. I can also update the givenName attribute, so I don't think there are any communication issues with the server.

I am doing the following encoding with my password: 
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(('"' + "T3stPassw0rd!" + '"').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));

When I try to update unicodePwd, I get the below error 
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
];

On looking up similar issues, I came to understand that this can happen if the connection is not ldaps (mine is ldaps, am able to search and update another attribute) or if the encoding is incorrect. I am using the encoding that was recommended, but cannot seem to get my code to work.

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the permissions for this?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can infact update another field for the same user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have an example that is known to work:

[Example - Active Directory Change Password JNDI](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Example%20-%20Active%20Directory%20Change%20Password%20JNDI)

Comment: Thank you, I had it working with this example. But what I don't understand is why it was not working when I did my own encoding. This password worked when I did ldap modify using an ldif file, but not from the API.

Comment: The "plaintext" password must be enclosed in double quotes. Then the entire string (with double-quotes") must be UTF-16. https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/UnicodePwd#section-UnicodePwd-TheSyntaxOfTheUnicodePwdAttribute